# How to refresh javascript once page has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, refresh

I have pointers on a google map that I want to update without loading the whole map. The pointers can be places in a separate Javascript file, but how can I make this reload

1. Without refreshing the whole page
2. How can I refresh the JS every 30 secs or so..

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {
          lat: ".$latitude.",
          lng: ".$longitude."
        }
      });

      setMarkers(map);

    }


    var beaches = [");


        echo("['".$name.
          "', ".$lat.
          ",".$long.
          "],");


        function setMarkers(map) {

          var image = {
            url: '1.png',

          };

          var shape = {
            coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
            type: 'poly'
          };
          for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
            var beach = beaches[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {
                lat: beach[1],
                lng: beach[2]
              },
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              shape: shape,
              title: beach[0],
              zIndex: beach[3]
            });
          }
        }
  </script>

  <script async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVQaENEYHY2g-mRhD6_tj1cSK8DhQoqHI&callback=initMap'>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code seem invalid? I cannot see where Javascript/PHP code starts or ends.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the map with JS would not refresh the page. If you need any communication to be done with backend, you can use AJAX.

Yes

```
setInterval(function(){
    // this function will be called at specific intervals
}, timeInMiliseconds);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks it has provoked thought.

I have tried to

function refresh()
     {

      setMarkers(map);

      var refresher = setTimeout('refresh()', 1000);
     }

But still no luck as I think I need function initMap()